# who -b shows different output format on Mac and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, who

I am trying to find a way to get output format of who -b same as in linux but on OSX i get format as below.

MAC

```
% locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
% who -b
reboot   ~        Nov  4 08:52
```

LINUX

```
[root@jump-host1 ~]# who -b
         system boot  2020-10-28 07:53
[root@jump-host1 ~]#
```

LOCALE is same on both linux and mac. How to get same format as linux on mac output of who -b

Also i found these properties are getting inherited when i do ssh to linux host is what i understood but when i run who -b as root i get the above output from linux.

**OSX**

```
bash-3.2$ alias who;type who;ldd $(type -p who) 
bash: alias: who: not found
who is /usr/bin/who
bash: ldd: command not found
bash-3.2$
```

**LINUX**

```
[jump-host1 ~]$ alias who;type who;ldd $(type -p who) 
-bash: alias: who: not found
who is /usr/bin/who
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc5aaa4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f62620b3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6262481000)
```

Comment: After you trying to determine the last time the system rebooted  in a program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [who -b date format varies strangely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98793/who-b-date-format-varies-strangely)